# Reading multiples uneven .csv files in one dataframe with R

Tags: r, csv

I need the following help if possible please let me know your comments

My ObjectTive:-

I had multiples .csv files one location.
all .csv files have different numbers of row(m) and column (n) i.e. m=!n
all csv files have an almost similar date (Calendar day & time stamps eg: 04/01/2016 7:01) but the interesting point is some data have some time stamps missing
All .csv files have following data common ( Open,High,Low, Close,Date).
My Objective is to import only "Close" column from all .csv files but each file have different numbers of rows as some time stamps data is missing in some files.

1. If on any case any time stamps data is missing but the previous present then repeat previous values.
2. If on any case any time stamps data is missing and the previous also missing then put 'NA' on it. This is only applicable for first few data points.

Here is my planning:-

1. Reading/Writing Files: We’ll need to implement a logic to read files in a certain fashion and then write separate files for different sets of instruments separately.
2. Inconsistent time series: You’ll notice that the time series is not consistent and continuous for some securities, so you need to generate your own datetime stamps and then fill data against each datestamp (wherever available).
3. Missing data points: There will be certain timestamps against which you don’t have the data, make your timeseries continuous by filling in the missing points with data from pervious timestamp.

Comment: Just to add that here I had total 5 files to read, each file has different no of columns. I am interested in Close column values from all five files, if any value missing for any time stamps in any file then we should repeat previous value on that file.

Comment: Inconsistent timeseries: You’ll notice that the time series is not consistent and continuous for some securities, so you need to generate your own datetime stamps and then fill data against each datestamp (wherever available).

Comment: Missing datapoints: There will be certain timestamps against which you don’t have the data, make your timeseries continuous by filling in the missing points with data from pervious timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
read_in <- function(csv){
             f <- read.csv(csv)
             f <- f[!is.na(f$time_stamp),]
             f$close
}

l <- lapply(csv_list, read_in)
df <- rbindlist(l)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Many thanks for your answer, I think above code does not fulfil my requirement. I had updated my requirement, pls check. Also, i had used following code,
library(data.table)

setwd("C:/Users/eghoshu/Documents/Rawdata")
csv_list = dir(path="C:/Users/eghoshu/Documents/Rawdata")
read_in <- function(csv){
  f <- read.csv(csv)
  f <- f[!is.na(f$times),]
  f$close
}
l <- lapply(csv_list, read_in)
df <- rbindlist(l)

Comment: Error message:- > l <- lapply(csv_list, read_in)
> df <- rbindlist(l)
Error in rbindlist(l) : 
  Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list